# Cant extract email from facebook iOS SDK 3.1

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to get user email address from Facebook iOS sdk (3.1) but cant seem to find a way to do that. I have added email as the permission in `requestToMe` but the `FBGraphUser` object returned in

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Does not have an email property at all. Is there another API call to get user email?

Thanks

Comment: Take the access token and run it in the debugger to make sure it has the email permission: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your application in Facebook and see if you can get the email address when you reauthorize. If you authorized the application and then added code to get the email, you won't be able to get the email from Facebook accounts that previously authorized it.

I've run in to this issue in the past.

Comment: hmm but FBGraphUser doesnt have an email property at all as per the docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/protocol/FBGraphUser

Comment: I think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843968/facebook-sdk-3-0-how-to-receive-users-e-mail