# Save Facebook e-mail address in Parse Databrowser

Tags: ios, facebook, email, parse-platform

After logging in with Facebook SDK. I am able to create a new PFUser but the e-mail address of this user does not save in my Databrowser. How can I get this done?

Action for the button:

```
- (IBAction)didTapFb:(id)sender {

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
if (![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
        [PFFacebookUtils linkUser:user permissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded) {
                NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
            }
        }];

NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location", @"email"];

[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error en conexión." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MaintoLook" sender:self];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MaintoLook" sender:self];

        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
}];
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Save it as you would any PFObject...

Comment: @LyndseyScott could you help with some code? I don't know how to get the email first.

Comment: Here's how you access the email: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11844297/2274694 .  Here's how you save the PFObject: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-saving/iOS .

Comment: @LyndseyScott it works but not as I intended. What I actually want is for the email to be saved in the User Class of my Data Browser but it is actually creating a new class. I am adding an image to the question. Please View.

Comment: You have to save the object to the user, not to a brand new class. So when saving "currentUser" should be your class, ex: [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:email forKey:@"email"]; [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

Comment: @LyndseyScott Does it still working? It`s returning me nothing, wrong method.

Comment: @Milan1111 I don't know what you mean by "it." You should probably just post your own question to find out what's going wrong with your particular code...

Comment: @LyndseyScott I already posted the question. Can you check it, please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350412/parse-recieve-e-mail-fb-sdk