# Parse receive E-mail FB SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am in trouble with parse user`s email. I can take from user almost everything though fb graph api. But it does not contain email property. Any idea, how to get it? If I do NSlog it always returns null.

```
{
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"email", @"basic_info"];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        // Was login successful ?
        if (!user) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            }else {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
            // Callback - login failed
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commsDidLogin:)]) {
                [delegate commsDidLogin:NO];
            }
        }else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *prop = (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *)result;
                    NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.id forKey:@"fbid"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.first_name forKey:@"firstname"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.last_name forKey:@"lastname"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
                    NSString *mail = userData[@"email"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:mail
                                             forKey:@"email"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];


                    NSLog(@"prop %@", prop);



                }else {
                    NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
                    NSLog(@"Welcome Screen I am %@", [[PFUser currentUser] username]);
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            //HERE
            NSLog(@"Error getting the FB username %@", [error description]);
        }
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        // Callback - login successful
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commsDidLogin:)]) {
            [delegate commsDidLogin:YES];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: You do not have to do `saveInBackground` every time. Just do it when you're done editing `[PFUser currentUser]`

Comment: I know it already, it´s old piece of code. Don´T you know how to get email?

Comment: I do, but it is almost exactly like yours. http://pastebin.com/v9Uf7dWr

Comment: Yes but it`s returning the null value

Comment: Perhaps the email address is unconfirmed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20594547/2274694.

Answer (score 1):

Not every Facebook user exposes the same information as part of their public profile, the `email` field is one in particular where you need to accept that this will often NOT be exposed.

The `userData` NSDictionary you get back will only be populated with information the person has made public, so handle missing keys as needed per user.

Documentation to read:

- [Requesting permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#permissions)
- [Reading the user's information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#userinfo)

Comment: But if the user agree with the permissions, I can get his email, can`t I? There must be a way how to get the email, don`t you know about any?

Comment: @Milan1111 refer to the documentation links, if you've setup your permissions correctly and issue your graph query correctly you will get the information if it exists